# understanding emberjs model initialisation and dependency

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes, ember-data, models

I'm getting ember right now... means awesome and awful times both while learning and trying... Anyway I really hope someone can help understanding this:

My route-map is like that:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("login");
  this.resource("institute", { path: '/institute/:institute.id/' }, function(){
    this.resource("all-cases", function(){
    });
  });
});
```

In my loginRoute, I load the model institutes with findAll which results in a array of institutes, thats why the controller is a ArrayController. Once the authentication was successful or verified I load the models via store from the API. They are being displayed by the view and I use them to trigger the action `selectInsitute` and transition to `all-cases`.

```
App.LoginRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  // login controller owns the institutes
  model: function(){
    return this.store.findAll('institute');
  },
  actions: {
    // this hook is called if authentication fails
    sessionAuthenticationFailed: function(message) {
      [...]
    },
    // this hook is called once the login was successfull
    sessionAuthenticationSucceeded: function(){
      this.controller.sessionAuthenticationSucceeded();
    }
  }
});

App.LoginController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(SimpleAuth.LoginControllerMixin,{
  authenticator: 'authenticator:custom',
  // authentication is done, now change some UI and load some models
  sessionAuthenticationSucceeded:  function (){
    [...]
    this.set('content', this.store.findAll('institute'));
  },
  actions : {
    selectInsitute : function(institute) {
      this.transitionToRoute('all-cases.index', institute);
    }
  }
});
```

My all-cases Route looks like this. **EDIT:I put the model definition as proposed by Steve H.** . Does the need actually do anything? It doesn't feel like it helps at all.

```
App.AllCasesRoute = Ember.Route.extend(SimpleAuth.AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  model: function(params, transition, queryParams){
    var instModel = this.modelFor('institute');
    console.debug(instModel);
    var cases = instModel.get('cases');
    console.debug(cases);
    return cases;
  }
});

App.AllCasesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ['login']
});
```

I put my two models in some kind of relationship like this, the case adapter is not working yet though due to my understanding problems how to put the instituteID in there the right way:

```
App.Institute = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  [...]
  cases: DS.hasMany('case')
});

App.InstituteAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  buildURL: function(type, id) {
    return '/api/core/insts'
  }
});

App.Case = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  institute: DS.belongsTo('institute')
});

App.CaseAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  buildURL: function(type, id){
    return '/api/core/institute/:instite_id/cases'
  }
});
```

Once I'm on the all-cases route my URI looks like this: `/#/institute/7/all-cases/`

The loading of the institutes on the LoginRoute works like a charm and the transition to the all-cases resource goes well too.
Following things I don't understand:

- Once I refresh the whole site on the `all-cases` route, all institute models are lost (I can see that via ember ff plugin) and they are not requested from the server anymore, I suppose because the route is not activated anymore which is responsible for loading the models via the store. How do I make sure that these models are always loaded and available via the LoginController?
- But apart from the problem that my institute data is lost on a refresh, how to a access selected institute on the `all-cases`route properly so the cases are going to be loaded from the API by the ID of the active institute, see URI, e.g. `7`
- How is everything gonna work once I selected a case and I'm gonna load more data which is dependent on both, the institute ID and the case ID?
- I'm using ember-simple-auth for authentication
- I design both, the api and the client so if you think that either of them is going the wrong way, please let me know
- I'm really stuck here and think I might face a design problem or at least an understanding problem. The guides and examples couldn't really help me anymore, they never deal with such dependency.
- **EDIT:** I put the modeldefiniton in the AllCases route like Steve H. proposed. Unfortunately it does not trigger a API request and once I refresh the page it gets even worse because my institutes are all lost and it does not try to request them either.

I hope I provided enough information about my design so far and anyone can actually understand my problems here. If I need to provide more, let me know...
Ember has been really great so far and I want to solve this badly just don't know how to continue.  Thank you in advance for any help on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are working with a sub-resource (like `cases`), you can get the parent resource with a call like this:

```
App.AllCasesRoute = Ember.Route.extend(SimpleAuth.AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  model: function(){
    return this.modelFor('institute').get('cases');
  }
});
```

The `modelFor` method (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_modelFor):

> Returns the model of a parent (or any ancestor) route in a route hierarchy. During a transition, all routes must resolve a model object, and if a route needs access to a parent route's model in order to resolve a model (or just reuse the model from a parent), it can call this.modelFor(theNameOfParentRoute) to retrieve it.

Also, remember when you use a router mapping like this:

```
this.resource("all-cases", function(){});
```

It will use `App.AllCasesIndexRoute` and `App.AllCasesIndexController` rather than this mapping:

```
this.resource("all-cases");
```

which will use `App.AllCasesRoute` and `App.AllCasesController`.

Also, the reason you are not making a request for cases can be fixed like this:

```
App.Institute = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  [...]
  cases: DS.hasMany('case', {async: true})
});
```

Without `{async: true}`, Ember will assume the data is coming in the payload with the `Institute`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Ok I just added `this.modelFor('institute').get('cases')` to the modeldefinition in the route. The modelFor returns a institute model and get('cases') returns a array with nothing in it. No API request is processed and the adapter for the case is not triggered at all. If I do a refresh on the page now I get even the js error: `TypeError: instModel.get is not a function: var cases = instModel.get('cases');`. It needs to  load the data from the server, but it doesn't. Your tip is probably right but how to I make it to talk to the API now? thanks again!

Comment: See my amended answer.

Comment: your answer now nails it mate, thank you very much...!